# One Feature to Rule Them All: Too Good to be True?

Tags: overfitting, feature-engineering, multi-class, medicine

I am trying to build a ML model for diagnosing a certain group of **several related but distinct diseases.** Using a publicly available medical dataset, I performed data cleaning and feature extraction, and now I am trying to train the actual model. (I am using CatBoost, but I think that is not particularly relevant).

My first experiment went **almost too well to believe.** After training the model to classify a specific disease from the group vs. healthy individuals, using a moderately-sized training and validation set (a couple 10 000s of samples), I achieved a ROC AUC of 0.99 on the hold-out test set, with a Youden's J score of about 0.9, and TPR and TNR equally around 95%.

This kind of performance with a bit of feature engineering and a relatively simple model doesn't seem realistic for the kind of problem I am trying to solve. Medical and biological data is known to be hard to classify. However, **I am pretty confident the model isn't overfit,** because the hold-out set was specifically engineered to avoid information leakage, it's reasonably-sized too (a couple 1000s of instances), and I set the hyperparameters of the model so that it's less prone to overfitting. I decreased the maximal depth of the trees to a mere 4 levels, and I ended up selecting the best 8 features out of an initial set of more than 100. I also tried several different random seeds to shake up the trees a bit, and the results were very similar.

However, I then tried to fit two other models for two different diseases. The results, again, were similarly good, and exceeded my expectations. However, I then plotted a chart of feature importances (CatBoost includes a built-in feature importance calculator based on SHAP values), and I made the observation that there was **a single dominant feature** which was always the most important for all three models.

I also tried removing this feature altogether, which lead to a significant decrease in model performance, but then the feature which was previously at the 2nd place became the universally most important one in a very similar manner.

At this point, I thought a bit about it, and I came to the conclusion that **there is probably something wrong with my methodology.** If each model relies on mostly the same single feature, then they are going to be highly correlated. Therefore, if one predicts a particular disease, the other two will also predict their respective two diseases with higher probability. This ultimately renders them way less useful, because they won't tell me much about a patient, except for a very general assessment of "they probably have one or more diseases" or "they are probably healthy".

I can't, however, find the error for sure. I have two theories as to what might be wrong:

- Although the diseases are distinct, they are still related, and as such, they are not mutually exclusive. In fact, a sizeable fraction of the individuals in the training dataset are diagnosed with two or more kinds of disease. This means that I am not performing true multi-class classification, strictly speaking. However, **it might still be that a true multi-class classifier would be more appropriate** for solving this kind of problem.
- There is **considerable imbalance** in both the train and the test set; only around 10 percent of patients are positive (diagnosed with at least one disease). However, class weights are input to the model prior to training, and anyway I don't see how class imbalance in itself might cause the phenomenon I am experiencing.

Do you have an idea as to what might be going on? Also, **should I continue modelling by excluding the feature in question,** or is it fine to keep it?

Comment: Did you select features or clean the data before the train/test split? If so, the test data has affected the training data, and you have implicitly selected features that are meaningful in both the training and testing data, which biases you toward success. You should select features and perform normalization in the training data only, and then apply that same normalization to the test data.

Comment: what is the feature?

Comment: such things can come up in observational data sets: eg imagine one of the features is "number of X assays" and all persons had atleast 1 X assay, but all diseased persons had to have a follow up to confirm. This makes the feature "number of X assays" perfectly correlated with disease status, but is completely non-causal

Comment: If you use a random-forest method like [Boruta](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Boruta/versions/7.0.0/topics/Boruta), what are the top-10 most important columns and does that make sense?  This is not a bad way to detect, identify, and mitigate any falsely-informative columns.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie No, I didn't. The split is pre-defined, as it is based on the recommendation of the authors of the database. I performed feature selection purely based on the train set, after splitting.

Comment: @bdeonovic The feature in question is heart rate variability (basically the standard deviation of the time differences between heart beats), and I am trying to predict various heart rhythm abnormalities. While it does make perfect sense that the irregularity of the length of heartbeats correlates with heart rhythm abnormalities, I have doubts about it being the universally most important _predictor_ for several, very specific kinds of heart diseases.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thanks for the suggestion! I ran a quick test using Boruta with sklearn's `RandomForestClassifier` as the base estimator (again, limiting the number of levels and trees to small-ish number in order to reduce overfitting). Oddly enough, 33 of the overall 46 features ended up being "definitely significant". The Boruta-based importance of the top 3 features agrees with the internal importance scores of CatBoost itself (meaning in particular that the top "superstar" feature is still #1 by a large margin).

Comment: How are the different heart diseases diagnosed? If all these forms of clinical arrhythmia are diagnosed by listening to the heart, it might make sense for a heartbeat-based feature to predict them all very well. But if some diagnoses are based on blood tests or other factors, it would be harder to believe.

Comment: @rbf - make sure the super-star is not falsely informative.  It may have too many categorical levels, it may have a hidden index, but "one to rule" is rare in the real world.  What happens when you plot the "one" against the outcome.  Consider a raincloud plot if the outcome is categorical.  For "limited number of trees" are we talking 100 or are we talking 10? Over-limiting is dangerous too.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That's a useful question to ask, thanks! I don't know how the diseases were diagnosed, but I think that is something I can find out.

Comment: For RF-based importance more is more, so you can do 500 trees at 20+ depth and get a solid job.  I find RF's importance does better with balanced classes, but that is more subjective.

Comment: @EngrStudent I actually tried several combinations of hyperparameters, the extremes were 100 trees with 8 levels vs. 32 trees with 4 levels. I'll try increasing the depth and number of trees, then. As for the raincloud plots, it's pretty clear there is an excellent correlation between the target and the superstar feature: [Plot](https://www.picallow.com/figure-1/).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie In the paper describing this database, the authors claim that the diagnoses were obtained from two cardiologists looking at the ECG of the patient and then agreeing on one or more disease (or the "healthy" label).

Comment: @rbf - try 200 trees (n_estimators), 20 levels (max_depth), and balanced (class_weight).  Also, make sure to use [intellex](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/), because it is a huge speedup (~16x on xgboost, which is pretty optimized out the gate), and n_jobs equals number of cores minus 1.  You might want to rerun a dozen times and look at the ensemble, or use something like [the critical differences diagram](https://www.timeseriesclassification.com/results.php).

Comment: Your classification is just binary healthy vs diseased right?I don't find it particularly surprising that heart rate variability is a good predictor of heart abnormality. I suggest you start of simpler. Look at some visualizations, how good is just simply logistic regression with just the heart rate variability?

Perhaps I would be surprised if heart rate variability was able to differentiate between different diseases.

Comment: @bdeonovic Yes, you are right. I have actually tried logistic regression, a linear SVM, and linear discriminant analysis on that single variable. They are pretty good (although not terrific) predictors, with AUCs around 75% and TPR/FPR at max Youden's J around 80/20%. Your last sentence actually gave me an idea – I'll make some raincloud plots for differentiating between 2 disease classes instead of healthy vs. one disease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your concern; it is completely feasible and possible (maybe even expected) that one feature discriminates healthy vs not-healthy individuals when those non-healthy individuals are suffering from distinct but related diseases. (Assuming there isn't some problem with the data). This isn't a question that can be answered using statistics and data mining; it has to do with the nature of the variable in question.

If your goal is to just identify disease (but not differentiate between diseases) then it seems like you have found a very strong indicator. I imagine this single variable won't be able to differentiate between the diseases though (which is probably ultimately what you want to do).

I don't understand your final theories: "it might still be that a true multi-class classifier would be more appropriate" What is appropriate? You define what appropriate is. Do you want to be able to differentiate between diseases? Then you should use a multi-class classifier. Do you just want to identify disease or not-disease?

Comment: Re your last question: neither is _exactly_ my goal. Ideally, the goal would be to identify _all_ diseases that apply. This means that "healthy vs. disease" is (much) better than nothing, but I definitely don't want the detection of one disease to automatically exclude detecting other diseases. This, in my understanding, means that it's not a classic multi-class problem, either. This is exactly why I started with several binary classifiers of the form healthy-vs-disease1, healthy-vs-disease2, etc. But these diseases might in fact be strongly correlated, after all.